# iOS UITextView attributedText <img> position

Tags: ios, css, uitextview, rtf, nsattributedstring

I have this RTF in my UITextView object:

```
"Test text <img src='http://icons.kdaweb.com/commerce/png/50x30/payment_types-american_express.png'> test text.
```

And result is [here](http://prntscr.com/9pwxvd)

I need to move image for few pixels under baseline, but `<img style=...>` doesn't work.

What can i do with image without using **UIWebView** ?

**SOLUTION:**

One style attribute works for me:

```
img {vertical-align:-5px;}
```

Comment: The CSS doesn't apply when you use the style attribute ?

Comment: I can change just Width and Height in style

Comment: how did you add image, using NSTextAttachemnt ?

Comment: <img src='[link to image]'>

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest you to use the **UIWebView**. Writing the img tag don't let you many choices. Using this class will help to well structure your code, avoiding any non maintainable code.

Then you'll be able to play with a CSS sheet, I really prefere the `UIWebView` solution.

### Edit

A way I don't recommend but could be a (bad) solution: make bigger the text and change `img` height to the text height. But you'll need to have a better image (SVG ?).